# What HTML attributes are allowed in Javadoc?

Tags: javadoc

I tried to use the [`lang` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang) on an element in a documentation comment. Doclint (as part of the `javadoc` command) rejects that. I know I could suppress HTML errors in general, but I want to be told actual HTML errors.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30957355/3273130) from 2015 lists allowed HTML tags, but I couldn’t even find a list of allowed attributes on tags.

Currently, for my specific problem, I added a custom taglet that transforms `{@foreignterm de Hallo Welt}` into `<i lang="de">Hallo Welt</i>`, but that’s not really close to optimal.

So I wonder how I could use `<i lang="de">Hallo Welt</i>` in a documentation comment. If it’s just not possible, which HTML attributes are allowed in Javadoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is documented anywhere, but [the source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/54957ac55f8c6c68efc80436417ff30d4e9e2d37/src/jdk.javadoc/share/classes/jdk/javadoc/internal/doclint/HtmlTag.java) is easy enough to understand:

e.g.

```
A(BlockType.INLINE, EndKind.REQUIRED,
        attrs(AttrKind.OK, HREF, TARGET, ID),
        attrs(AttrKind.HTML4, REV, CHARSET, SHAPE, COORDS, NAME))
```

The first argument (AttrKind) represents the validity. Possible values are: OK, INVALID, OBSOLETE, HTML4.

So for an anchor element, the 'href', 'target' and 'id' attributes are always okay. The 'rev', 'charset', etc. attributes are not supported in HTML5 (and you'll get [this error](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/54957ac55f8c6c68efc80436417ff30d4e9e2d37/src/jdk.javadoc/share/classes/jdk/javadoc/internal/doclint/resources/doclint.properties#L90))

Italic tags, like you tried to add an attribute to, do not accept any attributes.

```
 I(BlockType.INLINE, EndKind.REQUIRED,
     EnumSet.of(Flag.EXPECT_CONTENT, Flag.NO_NEST))
```