# How to create multiple levels of indentations with different markings in Javadoc?

Tags: java, html, javadoc

This question comes from the fact that I try to recreate an already existing java docs document for learning purposes which has multiple levels of indentations where the next level of indentation has a different marking than the first one. I am trying to recreate this behavior.

It should look like this:

[image]

This is a refinement on this already answered question [How to create multiple levels of indentation in Javadoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478777/how-to-create-multiple-levels-of-indentation-in-javadoc)

So far I only know how to create the bold black dots. Nesting does not changes the markings appearance, only creates the indentation.

```
<ul>
   <li> Example executions: </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried nesting the second `<ul>` *within* the `<li>` element, as suggested in the comments of the answer you linked?

Comment: Of course, but as I said it only results in indenting but not any difference in appearance of the mark.

Comment: I just tried and it does change the mark. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS for this and give the `<ul>` or `<ol>` tag the attribute `style="list-style-type:YOURTYPE`. This way you can specify the appearence.

```
<ul>
    <li> Foo </li>
    <ul style="list-style-type:circle">
        <li> Bar </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

For `unordered lists` there are the following possibilities:

> **disc**        Default. A filled circle.
>
> **circle**      An unfilled circle.
>
> **square**    A filled square.

If you are going to use `ordered lists` as well, a search engine will do the work and tell you all possibilities for the style.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to properly nest **within** the `<li>` element:

```
<ul>
    <li>Try this:
        <ul>
             <li>And this</li>
        <ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Which gives this result by default:

[image]

As opposed to:

```
<ul>
    <li>Try this:</li>
    <ul>
         <li>And this</li>
    <ul>
</ul>
```

Which does not change the type of mark.

Comment: Don't know why but for javadoc 7 this does not work for me using Linux and creating the javadoc through the terminal.

Comment: It seems weird to me. How do you read the generated html files?

Comment: With chrome? I simply just click on one of the generated .html files and navigate through there. I literally copy and pasted your example and put it in javadoc /** etc style. It did the same as I had before. I also expected it to auto change the mark when indenting.. but it didn't for me.